# where are repo's automated build files located

Tags: docker

On an automated build, how can I access the files from my private repo?

Ex if I have a Dockerfile with:

```
FROM node:4.1.1
npm install
```

Where are the files from my repo located?

Comment: You mean your repo for your containers?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you're asking?  Docker "Automated Builds" checkout a version control repository that you specified when creating the automated build, and then run "docker build" in that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Dockerfile has only:

```
FROM node:4.1.1
npm install
```

That won't involve any git repo (public or private)

You could add a `RUN git clone git@bitbucket:myaccount/myprivaterepo /path/to/repo` directive.

Or you can follow the [official docker node image instruction](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/node#how-to-use-this-image):

> Create a Dockerfile in your Node.js app project

```
FROM node:0.10-onbuild
# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 8888
```

> You can then build and run the Docker image:

```
$ docker build -t my-nodejs-app .
$ docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app my-nodejs-app
```

**In that case, your node app will be in `/usr/src/app`**.
See [`onbuild/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/d798690bdae91174715ac083e31198674f044b68/0.10/onbuild/Dockerfile#L3-L8):

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN npm install
ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app
```

> The image assumes that your application has a file named [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) listing its dependencies and defining its [start script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values).